# grep to output to include unmatched entries too

Tags: unix, awk, command-line, grep

I am trying to map entries in file 1 based on a match in file 2. I tried 
(grep -Ff file1 file2), join etc., but it only outputs the matching entries. For example,

```
File1:
Cat 
Dog
Fish
Horse

File2: (tab delimited)
Cat 'Meow Meow'
Dog Bark
Horse 'Gallop gallop'
```

'Meow Meow' is a single word. column separator is only '\t'. The output I expect is,

```
Output file:
Cat Meow Meow
Dog Bark
Fish
Horse Gallop gallop
```

How can it be  done ?

Thanks in Advance,

AP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good case for ***join*** command:

```
join -j1 -o1.1,2.2 -t $'\t' -a1 <(sort File1) <(sort File2)
```

The output:

```
Cat     Meow Meow
Dog     Bark
Fish    
Horse    Gallop gallop
```

---

- `-o FORMAT` - obey *FORMAT* while constructing output line
- `-a FILENUM` - also print unpairable lines from file *FILENUM*, where *FILENUM* is 1 or 2

Comment: Good one! I don't know how you inferred the output given the man: `-o FORMAT obey FORMAT while constructing output line` though :)

Comment: @Aif, from `man join`: `FORMAT is one or more comma or blank separated specifications, each being 'FILENUM.FIELD' or '0'.`

Comment: @RomanPerkhrest. It works, but the problem is, it takes space as delimiter. i.e if second column has "Meow Meow". In the output it writes one Meow corresponding to cat !

Comment: @Arun, you didn't mention that your `File2` could have more than 2 columns. That's slightly another case. In most simple case you can extend your output with `-o1.1,2.2,2.3`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, sorry if I was not clear. But it is not more than two columns but a single word with a space inserted. thats is why I put "Meow Meow". The only column separator is '\t'

Comment: @Arun, update your `File2` according to new condition

Answer (score 1):

with `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {print $1, a[$1]}' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 1):

Ugglyest answer ever, using Perl (you didn't get any answer at the time):

```
$ perl -e '%actions = (); open my $fh ,"<", $ARGV[0] ; while (<$fh>) { chomp ; $actions{$_} = ""; } close $fh; open $fh, "<", $ARGV[1] ; while (<$fh>) { chomp; ($animal, $action) = split /\s+/; $actions{$animal} = $action; } foreach (keys %actions) { print "$_ $actions{$_}\n"; } ; ' file1 file2
Horse Gallop
Fish 
Dog Bark
Cat Meow
```

**Update**: limiting split.

```
$ perl -e '%actions = (); open my $fh ,"<", $ARGV[0] ; while (<$fh>) { chomp ; $actions{$_} = ""; } close $fh; open $fh, "<", $ARGV[1] ; while (<$fh>) { chomp; ($animal, $action) = split (/\s+/, $_, 2); $actions{$animal} = $action; } foreach (keys %actions) { print "$_ $actions{$_}\n"; } ; ' file1 file2
```